# spring boot docker overriding property is not working

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-volume

I am creating a docker image from the spring boot application and then running the image with following command.

`docker run -it -p 8081:8080 -v D:/data:/data -e m1_filepath:/data/m1.csv -e m2_filepath:/data/m2.csv image:1.0`

but it says `*.csv` path doesn't exist.

I build the jar with `mvn clean install` and

I have this docker file for spring boot

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I did check the jar file is copied while creating the docker image.
what can go wrong here and how should I debug?

Comment: Is the problem that you're docker image doesnt run at all or is it already your application which tells you that it can't find these files?

Comment: It's the app apolication that tells it can't find a path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo

-e m1_filepath=/data/m1.csv

iso

-e m1_filepath:/data/m1.csv